# Android ViewPager setOnTouchListener

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager component, and inside the fragment, there is a WebView component, I want to detect user's tap on screen, and at the same time, user can swipe also.

Currently I am settings the onTouchListener on ViewPager like this:
            vPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            float oldX = 0, newX = 0, sens = 5;

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                oldX = event.getX();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                newX = event.getX();
                if (Math.abs(oldX - newX) < sens) {
                    tap();
                    return true;
                }
                oldX = 0;
                newX = 0;
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I find the listener is triggered only when I swipe left and right, when I swipe up and down, it's not triggered. I am swiping on the WebView component, and it has long content which need scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking only for the X, up and down moves on the Y axis

Comment: no, I add debug point at the entry of onTouch method, its only got triggered when I swipe left and right.

Comment: Then the webview gets the event, try implementing it's onTouchListener and see if it gets the event, if so, move the listener as a variable and assign both views to it

Comment: because of the pager, it's only interested in the left-right swipes to show next-previous fragment, it's not interested in the up/down.It's pretty much how the android desktop works too, only far more restrictive there, when you swipe left-right you go to the screen and the widgets can only implement up-down gestures and tap

Comment: but you know, I can add listener to WebView, but the webView is inside Fragment, I cannot pass the event to ViewPager...

Comment: Then try to implement an observer pattern and pass the events to the pager